# How to set a new line character in gdal_edit.py when editing TIFFTAG_IMAGEDESCRIPTION?

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff

I have a sample image from DigitalGlobe site, where TIFFTAG_IMAGEDESCRIPTION field reported by gdalinfo looks as follows:

```
TIFFTAG_IMAGEDESCRIPTION={
  bandList = 
  [
    6;
    2;
    3;
    7;
    4;
    8;
    5;
    9;
  ]
}
```

I want to set a description in multiband tiff from command line, but I can't guess how to set a new line character ("\n" doesn't work). How to set a new line character in gdal_edit.py when editing TIFFTAG_IMAGEDESCRIPTION?

```
gdal_edit.py -mo TIFFTAG_IMAGEDESCRIPTION='{band_list = [ 2; 3; 4 ]}' B2-B3-B4.TIF
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really know whether it helps (haven't tried it), but wouldn't using `printf` work? Eg

```
gdal_edit.py -mo TIFFTAG_IMAGEDESCRIPTION="$(printf '{\nband_list = \n[\n 2;\n 3;\n 4;\n]\n}')" my_file.tif
```

I'm assuming you're using the BASH shell.

Comment: thank you, printf did the trick! I've slightly edited the answer